# How to parse IP Address or Host name containing Alpha Characters?

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to separate two different types of Strings, IP addresses and DNS addresses. I am having trouble figuring out how to split it. My initial thought is:

```
String stringIP = "123.345.12.1234";
String stringDNS = "iam.adns234.address.com";

if(!Pattern.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9.]*$",stringDNS)){
    //I only want to get IP type strings here, so I am trying to separate out anything containing alpha characters. `stringDNS` should not be allowed into the if statement.
}
```

Comment: The first `stringIP` is invalid, because it has four digits in the last group.

Comment: yes, I just was just trying to get my intent across, thanks

Comment: Can't you distinguish between a letter and a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static final String IPV4_REGEX = "\\A(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|[0-1]?\\d?\\d)(\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|[0-1]?\\d?\\d)){3}\\z";
if(string.matches(IPV4_REGEX)
{
    //....
}
```

Note that the IP address you posted "123.345.12.1234" is not a valid IPV4 addrss.

Comment: This worked great, and yes I know that it isn't valid, I was trying to get my intent across, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can "validate" your IP with the following pattern:

```
String stringIP = "123.345.12.1234";
String stringDNS = "iam.adns234.address.com";
//                | start of input
//                | | 1-4 digits
//                | |      | dot
//                | |      |    | 3 occurrences
//                | |      |    | | 1-4 digits
//                | |      |    | |       | end of input
String pattern = "^(\\d{1,4}\\.){3}\\d{1,4}$";
System.out.println(stringIP.matches(pattern));
System.out.println(stringDNS.matches(pattern));
```

**Output**

```
true
false
```

**Note**

Validation here is "lenient", insofar as it won't check the values and will fit your example with up to 4 digit items.

For a more serious validation (with the down side of a less readable pattern), see [dasblinkenlight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/335858/dasblinkenlight)'s answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation would let through some strings that do not represent a digital IP address. It is better to use a regex that passes through only valid numeric IP addresses. The regex is [taken from here](http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-ip-address-with-regular-expression/). It is somewhat complex, because it needs to ensure that multi-digit numbers are below 256, but it is a solid way of validating a numeric IP address:

```
String IPADDRESS_PATTERN = 
    "^([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
    "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
    "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
    "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$";
if(Pattern.matches(IPADDRESS_PATTERN, stringIP)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As validating a domain String is a more complex task, if you don't mind, you can add an extra lightweight apache commons library to your project.

Have a look at [DomainValidator.isValid(String)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/DomainValidator.html#isValid-java.lang.String-).

Please note that this method also checks for valid well-recognized top-level domain names (.com, .org, etc).

For validating IP addresses have a look at [InetAddressValidator.isValidInet4Address(String)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/InetAddressValidator.html#isValidInet4Address-java.lang.String-).